# WordPress prevent specific posts from query with elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, restriction

I am trying to manipulate an elementor query for all post types. I am using the Profile Builder plugin to restrict content. Their support sent me this function to check wether the post is restricted or not:

```
wppb_content_restriction_is_post_restricted( $post_id )
```

When I output the result of this function on the post it is either 1 or nothing. (1 being restricted).

The support also send me a custom addon-plugin of another plugin they have, where I'd only need to add the new function. When I do this and install it to my page, nothing changes though.

Here is the code of their mini plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Paid Member Subscriptions - Exclude Restricted Posts From Query
Plugin URI: http://www.cozmoslabs.com
Description: Exclude restricted posts and pages from the main queries like blog, archive and taxonomy pages. It does not exclude them from custom queries.
Author: Cristian Antohe
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.cozmoslabs.com
*/

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pmsc_exclude_post_from_query' );
function pmsc_exclude_post_from_query( $query ) {

    remove_action('pre_get_posts', 'pmsc_exclude_post_from_query');

    if( !function_exists( 'pms_is_post_restricted' ) || is_admin() || is_single() )
        return;

    if( $query->is_main_query() || ( $query->is_search() && isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) ) {
        $args = $query->query_vars;
        $args['suppress_filters'] = true;
        $args['posts_per_page'] = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
        $posts = get_posts($args);

        $ids = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' );
        $restricted_ids = array_filter($ids,'pms_is_post_restricted');

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $restricted_ids );
    }
}
```

In case that a post is restricted, I want to exclude it from my query. So that the user only sees posts that can be accessed.

Now the challenge is to write a custom query that I can then put inside of the query ID of elementor's post widget to perform my custom query.

My query looks like this so far:

```
function prevent_restricted_posts_from_loading( $query ) {

    if( !function_exists( 'wppb_content_restriction_is_post_restricted' ) || is_admin() || is_single() )
        return;

    if( $query->is_main_query() || ( $query->is_search() && isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) ) {
        $args = $query->query_vars;
        $posts = get_posts($args);

        $ids = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' );
        $restricted_ids = array_filter($ids,'wppb_content_restriction_is_post_restricted');

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $restricted_ids );
    }

}
add_action( 'elementor/query/prevent_restricted_posts_from_loading', 'prevent_restricted_posts_from_loading' );
```